# java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a regular expression for some path conversion.
Example for path are

```
//name:value /name:value // name:value
/name:value /name:value
/name:value//name:value
```

thing is how to check for // or / at the start or middle of the string and how can i specify that name can contain any of this a-zA-Z and _

Path also contains white spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help:

```
String s = "//name:value /name:value // name:value";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("//?\\s*(\\w+):(\\w+)\\s*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.printf("%s = '%s'%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

Some notes:

- It is assumed the `/` or `//` can delineate `name:value` pairs;
- Optional white space after `/` or `//` and after `name:value` is ignored;
- Both `name` and `value` are captured. You don't say what you want to capture. Adjust the parentheses as necessary;
- Both `name` and `value` consist of A-Z, a-z, 0-9 or _ (that's what `\w` means).

If you don't want to find the values but simply test for the validity as a whole:

```
String s = "//name:value /name:value // name:value";
if (s.matches("(//?\\s*\\w+:\\w+\\s*)+")) {
  // it fits
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What exaclty do you want to archieve? Do you just want to check if an input is a valid path, or do you want to extract any matched groups for further conversion?

In any case a pattern that would match a string starting with / or // and a name and value consisting of a-zA-Z and _ would be:

```
(//?\s*[A-Za-z_]+:[A-Za-z_]+\s*)+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `replaceAll` to do the transformation if it's simple enough.

```
    String strings = "//cello:Yo-Yo Ma  / violin : Itzhak Perlman";
    System.out.println(strings.replaceAll(
        "//?\\s*(\\w+)\\s*:\\s*(.*?)\\s*(?=/|$)",
        "[$2] on [$1]\n"
    ));
    // "[Yo-Yo Ma] on [cello]"
    // "[Itzhak Perlman] on [violin]"
```